# Visual Studio keeps asking for the location of a source file while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, html-agility-pack

In my c#-project I use the HtmlAgilityPack. Everything worked fine for weeks, but today, when I run the code in Debug Mode and code related to the HtmlAgilityPack is used, VS keeps asking me for the location of "HtmlNode.cs" which is a class within the HtlmAgilityPack.dll. When I choose "Cancel", VS crashes.

I don´t even have any breakpoints set. I cleaned and rebuilt the solution, deleted obj and bin folders, renamed "HtmlAgilityPack.pdb", deleted the temp-folder in the %APPDATA%-directory and also deleted and re-set the link to the assembly. Nothing worked.

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Try Debug>Options, on the Debugging/General options find and select "Enable Just My Code". What is happening is that something in HTMLAgilityPack is throwing an exception (probably due to your code) but the debugger is trying to break there instead of the function that is causing the exception.

Comment: @Ron: that option is already checked. I also put the "critical" code into a try-catch-block.

Comment: Could you try and re-install the HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: @Chris: Just did, but it didn´t help.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue you have to enable below under **`In Debug >> Options >> Debugging/General`**

- (Show disassembly if source is not available) under Enable address-level debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on VS C++ project. I deleted all the breakpoints and it worked for me: Debug -> Delete All Breakpoints (or use shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + F9).

Answer (score 0):

I still have no solution on how to avoid VS trying to debug into the source file, but thanks to Ron, I figured out, that an exception in the source file was the cause for the problem and so I changed my code accordingly, so that any Exception would be avoided. (In may case, I tried to remove an Attribute in an HtmlNode which wasn´t there.)